# Does Spark support accessing data from master node or worker node?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Is it possible to create a RDD using data from master or worker? I know that there is a option `SC.textFile()` which sources the data from local system (driver) similarly can we use something like "`master:file://input.txt`" ? because I am accessing a remote cluster and my input data size is large and cannot login to remote cluster.

I am not looking for `S3` or `HDFS`. Please suggest if there is any other option.

Comment: What cluster manager you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Data in an RDD is always controlled by the Workers, whether it is in memory or located in a data-source.  To retrieve the data from the Workers into the Driver you can call `collect()` on your RDD.

You should put your file on HDFS or a filesystem that is available to all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to as you stated use `sc.textFile`. To do that you need to make the file available on all nodes in the cluster. Spark provides an easy way to do this via the `--files` option for spark-submit. Simply pass the option followed by the path to the file that you need copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the hadoop, file by creating hadoop configuration.

```
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, InputStream}

val hadoopConfig = SparkHadoopUtil.get.conf
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(fileName), hadoopConfig)
val fsPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(fileName)
```

Once you get the path you can copy, delete, move or perform any operations.